# Why does this always return true? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def follows(follower, followed)
follow = Follows.where("follower = ? AND followed = ?", follower, followed)
if follow
    true
  else 
    false
  end
end
```

Here is my view code:

```
<% if current_user.id == @user.id%>
  <p>This is you!</p>
<% else %>
  <% if follows(current_user.id, @user.id)%>
    <p>You already follow <%= @user.username %>
  <% else %>
    <p><%= link_to "Follow!", follow_path(@user.id) %></p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to check if a user follows another, so wrote this. It takes in two user ids, and queries the Database, and ***should*** return true when a match is found and false otherwise. But it always return true. Why is this?

Comment: You would have to look in the *Follows.where* method surely?

Comment: If the function accepts ids, then the parameter names should be follower_id and followed_id. Reserve follower and followed for when you have real instances, and not just the ids.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with some style and design issues and end with the actual answer:

1. Models are singular by convention. Doing otherwise will only cause you more work. In this case, I would suggest `Following` as a suitable name, as in "a user has many followings".
2. Foreign keys should end with `_id`. Doing otherwise will only cause you more work. So `follower_id` and `followed_id`.
3. Methods that are intended to be used for their true/false nature ("[query methods](http://reinh.com/blog/2008/07/16/ruby-patterns-query-method.html)") should end with a ?, so `follows?` instead of `follows`,
4. Your if statement is redundant and can be safely removed once the condition does the right thing. In ruby, in the context of conditionals, we care more about whether things *evaluate* to true/false than whether they are literally `true` or `false`. This means that anything other than `nil` or `false` will be "truthy".
5. The fact that your method depends entirely on information known to `User` objects indicates that it would be better to hang it off of those objects, for instance `current_user.follows? other_user`.
6. You are duplicating behavior that would already be provided to you by using associations.

Finally, taking all of these things into consideration, the answer:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings, :class_name => 'Following', :foreign_key => 'followed_id'
  has_many :followers, :through => 'followings'

  def follows?(other)
    other.followed_by? self
  end

  def followed_by?(other)
    followers.include? other
  end
end
```

**NB**: The use of the `followed_by?` method here is a use of [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) that prevents the (minor) [Law of Demeter violation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter) of one user knowing directly about the state of another user's followers. Rather, the first user object asks the second user object a direct question  ("Are you followed by me?") and bases the result off of the answer. (It is also likely to be a useful method in and of itself.)

Comment: Thanks so much for showing me the proper, corrent way to do this, rather than just a quick fix!

Comment: What a thoughtful and complete answer.  Wish I had more than one upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it always returns true is that, even when no records are found, where() is returning an empty array.  An empty array is "true".  In other news, the structure:

```
if (condition)
  true
else
  false
end
```

Can be replaced by:

```
condition
```

Answer (score 1):

follow is actually an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation rather than the result set of your query. To work out find out if any rows would be returned by the query use follow.count. Eg.

```
if follow.count > 0
  true
else 
  false
end
```

Comment: and unless you are doing something else in the block, leave off the true else false end part

Answer (score 1):

You can use `present?`. Your code should be

```
  if follow.present?
    true
  else 
    false
  end
```

Comment: and unless you are doing something else in the block, leave off the true else false end part

Answer (score 0):

@rein Heinrichs answer is superb. He gives you the best Rails way to solve it. But i would like to explain why what you wrote does not work, and how you should fix that.

```
Follows.where(...)
```

returns an array, the easy way to verify this yourself is to run that line in the rails console (type `rails c` in the console). 
An array, even an empty one, is not `nil` and will always evaluate to `true`.

So to return a boolean depending on the fact whether or not any followers are found, just check for the amount of items inside the result of the `where` (use `size > 0` or `present?`)

So your `follows` function could then have been rewritten as:

```
def follows(follower, followed)
  Follows.where("follower = ? AND followed = ?", follower, followed).present?
end
```

and this is actually quite readable as well. Hope this helps.